# When using cakephp habtm, do I have to create relations in MySql too?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Or is it enough to have just the relations defined in the model. I have been trying to connect tables users and groups and got only to a point where only last connection in array got saved ...

Just to add, I am using table users_groups as a join table. This table tas fields user_id and group_id. Find all works like a treat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do as far as your database is concerned is to make sure you're using the correct table name and field(s).  Then, as long as you have your model associations set up correctly, you should be good to go.

In your case, your table should be 'groups_users', not 'users_groups' (they should be in alphabetical order).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I know about that. The problem is that I am not using the forms helper to buld the forms. What would be the dataset than that is coming to the db if let's say the user would have just a name column so I can save it programmatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  But if you don't know how the data should be, just use the FormHelper to build it, submit it, and see how the data is, then build it yourself manually (not sure why you'd do that, but... it would tell you how the data should be submitted)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that!!?? Thx!